# Why blockchain structure is used in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I have a problem with understanding why Hyperledger Fabric (HLF) uses blockchain structure.

I know that in Bitcoin blockchain structure ensures big security due to PoW algorithm and longest chain rule, but what are advantages of using a blockchain structure in HLF?

It seems to me that in Hyperledger Fabric, instead of the blockchain structure, there could be one transaction history log and network could work in the same way - I bet I'm wrong, but I haven't been able to find an explanation yet.

I would be grateful for the clarification of this issue.

Comment: Mainly because the Hyperledger project is a collection of blockchain systems. There is Fabric, Burrow, Iroha, Sawtooth etc - all blockchain architectures that have different strengths and weaknesses. If Fabric does not use a blockchain structure then it would stop being part of the Hyperledger project.

Comment: Note that if you personally don't need blockchain then you don't need to use any of the Hyperledger blockchains - just use Mysql or Oracle or Mongodb and implement an audit table and you will have what you want. But if you need blockchain, that is you need the security of nobody being able to modify the data - not even the database admin then you can use one of the Hyperledger blockchain. If you need a blockchain but don't want to create your own then you should use one of the public blockchains that is already deployed such as Bitcoin or Ethereum

Comment: Thanks, audit table is interesting and a new thing for me, however it does not guarantee the properties guaranteed by blockchain or another distributed ledger technology (DLT). I'll try precise my question. I'm trying to understand if the blockchain structure is really needed in Hyperledger Fabric and other Hyperledger projects. Maybe another DLT could be enough (maybe DLT working only as log of operations)? For example Corda is a permissioned DLT and doesn't use blockchain. So maybe the blockchain structure in HLF is one of the many possibilities for this network to work and isn`t required?

Comment: By checking the hash of the last block you can find out if the whole chain is correct. With the log of operations (or blocks but without previous blocks hashes) I could check it as well, it would only take more time to check. Is this time difference the only one that exists between the DLT based on the log of operations and the blockchain structure in HLF? I am writing a master's thesis on blockchain, please be understanding, because I know that this question may sound strange and incomprehensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a lot of questions you have in your mind comes from the overlapped definitions of DLT and blockchain.

**DLT**:

A DLT is simply a decentralized database that is managed by various participants. There is no central authority that acts as an arbitrator or monitor. As a distributed log of records, there is greater transparency – making fraud and manipulation more difficult – and it is more complicated to hack the system.

All of this could well be familiar because it’s written about the features of blockchain as well.

**Blockchain**:

Blockchain is nothing else but a DLT with a specific set of features. It is also a shared database – a log of records – but in this case shared by means of blocks that, as the name indicates, form a chain. The blocks are closed by a type of cryptographic signature called a ‘hash’; the next block begins with that same ‘hash’, a kind of wax seal. That is how it is verified that the encrypted information has not been manipulated and that it can’t be manipulated.

[image: difference between DLT and blockchain]

DLT platforms that are not blockchain provide immutability too, but it's just the way Hyperledger Fabric provides this characteristic which makes it a blockchain framework.

Every blockchain framework, be it the Ethereum, Bitcoin, etc all store the transaction information in blocks, where each block is linked to its predecessor by a hash and provides immutability.

Corda is very much similar to Hyperledger Fabric, but it is said to be both a blockchain and not a blockchain. Architecturally, it's very much similar to Hyperleder Fabric, but with only a key difference which makes Hyperledger Fabric a blockchain framework, and Corda a DLT.

I'll try to answer your question by emphasizing on the point that why Corda is not a blockchain.

**Why is Corda a blockchain, and not a blockchain?**

- A Transaction in Corda is cryptographically linked (chained) to the transactions it depends on. Just like Bitcoin, but the range of concepts that can be expressed is far wider.
- Transactions in Corda are processed by having each participant in the transaction execute the same code deterministically to verify the proposed updates to the ledger. Just like Ethereum, but the languages you can use are high-level and productive, like Java, rather than obscure ones like Solidity.
- Transactions in Corda are shared only with those who have a need to know. Just like channels in Fabric but designed in from day one and fully integrated into the programming model.
- Transactions in Corda are confirmed through a process of consensus forming using one of a range of algorithms, including Byzantine Fault Tolerant algorithms. Just like any other blockchain, but with the unique features that a Corda network can support multiple different consensus pools using different algorithms.

So, for all intents and purposes, Corda is a blockchain. And yet… there’s also an utterly critical difference.

Unlike the platforms mentioned above, Corda does not periodically batch up transactions needing confirmation — into a block — and confirm them in one go. Instead, Corda confirms each transaction in real-time. No need to wait for a bunch of other transactions to come along. No need to wait for a “block interval”. Each transaction is confirmed as we go.

Now coming onto your question **why Hyperledger Fabric (HLF) uses blockchain structure?** The answer is simply because they chose to.

References:

- https://www.bbva.com/en/difference-dlt-blockchain/
- https://cointelegraph.com/news/what-is-the-difference-between-blockchain-and-dlt
- https://www.corda.net/blog/corda-top-ten-facts-7-both-a-blockchain-and-not-a-blockchain/

Comment: Thanks, your answer explained a lot to me.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the record immutable, Hyperledger Fabric uses blockchain structure. So by using Hyperledger Fabric, you can get an immutable record of all the transactions which is tough to temper with fraudulent activities.

Suppose you buy an valuable asset and you are the current owner of that asset. Now it is very hard for others to temper that records or change your ownership without your permission as Hyperledger Fabric uses blockchain structure to keep the record immutable.

Comment: Yes, but a blockchain structure doesn't seem necessary to me for a private network/consortium. In public networks  (such as Bitcoin) using blockchain structure and PoW algorithm guarantees immutability, but it seems to me that in HLF this immutability could be achieved without blockchain structure. So maybe blockchain structure saves only time compared to a another distributed ledger technology (DLT), which only has a transaction log. If you want you can take a look also at my comment under the main question. Thanks